# Unable to create call adapter in retrofit 2.0.0

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am trying to integrate retrofit 2.0.0-beta in to my app.

```
{
     "success":true,
     "categoryDetails":[
    {
        "topicId":550,
        "categoryName":"Classshshs",
    “categoryImageUrl” : “http://s3-apdd-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/tv-dev/member/photo/883191-medium130.jpg”,
    },
    {
    "topicId":550661,
        "categoryName":"Cricket sss",
    “categoryImageUrl” : “http://s3-apdd-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/tv-dev/member/photo/883191-medium130.jpg”,
    }

   ],
   "totalCategoryCount":2
}
```

My rest adapter

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com").
                    addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    service=retrofit.create(RetrofitService.class);
```

My Call method

```
Call<Object> call=service.listRs();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<Object> response) {
            Log.e(TAG,"sucess"+response.toString());



        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {

        }
    });


Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for interface retrofit.Call
for method RetrofitService.listRs
        at retrofit.Utils.methodError(Utils.java:201)
        at retrofit.MethodHandler.createCallAdapter(MethodHandler.java:51)
        at retrofit.MethodHandler.create(MethodHandler.java:29)
        at retrofit.Retrofit.loadMethodHandler(Retrofit.java:138)
        at retrofit.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:127)
        at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:397)
        at $Proxy1.listRs(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a copy-paste problem, but your JSON is invalid: there's an extra comma after each `categoryImageUrl ` value.

Comment: Can you be specific about what error message you get? Is it a compilation error?

Comment: @akodiakson that is copy paste error..

Comment: http://paste.ofcode.org/sijPuCQTvYE3aJtdNnbmcJ

Comment: Can you paste that as an edit instead of a 3rd party site?

Comment: You are using Callback<Object>() with the GsonConverterFactory. Maybe create an object with the correct values?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in gradle

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'    
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. That's not the way to promote your website, please read [How not to be a spammer](/help/promotion).

Answer (score -1):

Try to use callback executor, like this:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com").
                addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .callbackExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1))
        .build();
```